# C#, send a value to a textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I have listbox of strings.  When I select one of this strings, I split it.

I want to send to the `textboxes` the split values of this string.  How do I send the values to the textboxes?

I have this C# code:

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Code;
    string Name;
    string PName;
    string Cost;
    string Num;
    string Level;

    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.Default))
    {
        if (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            Items.Add(streamReader.ReadLine());//list Items
        }
    }

    string z = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

    string[] words = x.Split(',');
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
       if (words.Length == 6)
       {
            Code = words[0];
            Name = words[1];
            PName = words[2];
            Cost = words[3];
            Num = words[4];
            Level = words[5];
        }                
    }

    textBox1.Text = Code;       //This does not send anything to the textbox
    textBox2.Text = Name;
    textBox3.Text = PName;
    textBox4.Text = Cost;
    textBox5.Text = Num;
    textBox6.Text = Level;

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(
           filePath, false, Encoding.Default))
    {
        foreach (string op in Items)
        {
            streamWriter.WriteLine(op);
        }
    }
}
```

The C# code that does `textBox1.Text = Code;` does not send any text to the textbox, how do I assign a string to a textbox?

Comment: You should name your controls.

Comment: What's the exact error your getting? It looks like if your split fails you'll be putting out defaults, but String.Empty should be fine for a TextBox.Text...

Comment: should... string[] words = x.Split(','); be... string[] words = z.Split(',');  ?

Comment: What is the purpose of the foreach, it is redundant, since the internals of the foreach refer to the words array

Comment: what is the error? Have you stepped into the code using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Code` variable is still null when you are assigning it to the `TextBox`.

Change it to:

```
string Code = string.Empty;
// etc.
```

Based on your sample code though, you shouldn't need any of those string variables or your ForEach.  Just assign it straight to your TextBoxes.

```
textBox1.Text = words[0];
textBox2.Text = words[1];
textBox3.Text = words[2];
textBox4.Text = words[3];
textBox5.Text = words[4];
textBox6.Text = words[5];
```

And try giving your controls names, too.  textBox4 doesn't tell you it has anything to do with cost.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `Code` will only contain a value if `words.Length == 6`. Make sure the variable contains a value.

Use this and see if text gets saved to the textbox:

```
textBox1.Text = "test";
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You assign the selected value of the listbox to z but then call Split on an undeclared variable x
2. The foreach (string word in words) doesn't make sense. You don't need it. Remove it (but not the body code of it)

Answer (score 0):

try using statement like assign it directly such as  textBox1.Text = Code.ToString(); or
  textBox1.Text=words[0].ToString(); maybe it might help you